# Java: how to clean array and reuse it at different size efficiently?

Tags: java, arrays

I change dimension of the array all the time. For instance :

```
Window = new float[bufferSizeWords];
```

and then I use same array, but twice longer

```
Window = new float[2*bufferSizeWords];
```

Since I don't have explicit control on garbage collection, do I have any ways to make such use memory more efficient? Does `Window=null` in between help in any way ?

Arrays are quite large and they cause out of memory exception on older smartphones...

Answer (score 0):

If you plan on resizing an array repeatedly, you should use an `ArrayList`. You can still choose an initial size when constructing it. If you exceed the initial capacity, it will double in size automatically for you.

Comment: I have simple Integers in arrays. I guess that dealing with ArrayList would not be so efficient ? Am I right ?

Comment: it may be fine for your use case and much less error-prone. First make it correct than optimize :)

Answer (score 0):

We dont have control over the place of an array when we increase its size, because the memory next to its end may be occupied by other objects, so it needs to be relocated to another free area where it can fit. This applies to both ArrayList objects and native arrays.

If no such area is found, the gc will surely run before throwing an OutOfMemoryError. That is, no need to invoke explicitly the gc to avoid such an error. Invoking the gc explicitly is rarely a good idea IMO.

To avoid the relocation of your array and be more flexible than requesting a contiguous memory area, you can ultimately build your own class that manages a collection of arrays (i.e. array of arrays), each chunk is some fixed size array, allocated when needed and freed (nulled) when no longer needed. Be sure to free (nullify) when no longer needed, to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: I've read somewhere that catching Out of Memory Error actually helped with memory efficiency - exactly because GC is started before exception would happen.. Is this right ?

Comment: @user2064070 why should it help? Since the only way to force the GC to run is when the memory error would actually occur? That might be the opinion of someone somewhere, but honestly I do not understand why catching OutOfMemoryError would improve performance in any way.